# DRM photo viewing in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I would like to write an enterpise app that displays some slides on the PC (think powerpoint deck)

important is the requirement that the user cannot take a screenshot of the picture, to see the image they must enter a password, I do not want them to be able to keep the picture

is this possible in Silverlight?  what about Flash?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean, how do you disable someone from using [Ctrl - Print Screen] on a PC or [Command-Shift-3] on a Mac?

Ummm... I think the best you could do is create and out of browser app that is fullscreen AND only when it becomes the active window, it will show the images you want to protect.  That way you can disable the keys for screen capture and prevent any other programs from capturing a window shot of your what is in your app.

Still, there is nothing preventing a fiddler user from capturing an image downloaded to your app from a webservice or something. All the images would have to be encrypted then decrypted by your app.

Looks like watermarking your images is your best bet.

Comment: there are some technologies that do this, in Outlook for example you cannot screenshot a rights protected email.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know that. Still they warn that IRM will not "Help prevent a recipient from taking a digital photograph of the protected information displayed on a monitor" or "Help prevent protected information from being copied by using third-party screen-capture programs". So I think the logic above still applies.